# How to move Column Header to row corresponding to specific values in excel using python?Please refer to attached snapshot

Tags: python, pandas

[Initial dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W3Jw.png) and [action I want to complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8iRg.png).

I am looking for help and support if we can move Column Header to the row corresponding to specific values in excel using python\pandas? Please refer to the attached snapshot.

Comment: Search for `df.melt()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function pd.wide_to_long which converts it to longform data:

```
df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='Data')
df2
```